Drag and Drop Widget How to make as smooth as before splitting into groups?
I am currently working on implementing drag and drop functionality for a view similar to how iOS widgets behave on the home screen. I have grouped views with a size of 1x1 so that, when they are close to each other and dragged, they move as a single block. However, after grouping them, the animations are no longer smooth, or the animations seem to be missing compared to before.

import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct Card: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let style: LayoutStyle
    let height: CGFloat
    
    static func ==(lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}


struct CardGroup: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let cards: [Card]
}


struct CardView: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var showEdit: Bool
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                Text(title)
                    .font(.title2)
            }
            
            if showEdit {
                Text("Edit")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct MockStore {
    static func cards() -> [Card] {
        [
            Card(title: "Small Card 1", style: .widget1x1, height: 1/1),
            Card(title: "Small Card 2", style: .widget1x1, height: 1/1),
            Card(title: "Small Card 3", style: .widget1x1, height: 1/1),
            Card(title: "Regular2x1", style: .widget2x1, height: 2/1),
            Card(title: "Small Card 4", style: .widget1x1, height: 1/1),
            Card(title: "Large 3x2", style: .widget2x3, height: 2/3),
            Card(title: "Large 2x2", style: .widget2x2, height: 2/2),
            Card(title: "Small Card 5", style: .widget1x1, height: 1/1),
            Card(title: "Small Card 6", style: .widget1x1, height: 1/1)
        ]
    }
}

enum LayoutStyle {
    case widget1x1
    case widget2x1
    case widget2x2
    case widget2x3
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cards: [Card] = MockStore.cards()
    @State private var isEdit: Bool = false
    @State private var draggedCard: Card?
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Button {
                        isEdit.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Edit")
                    }
                    
                    ForEach(groupedCards(), id: \.id) { group in
                        LazyHStack {
                            ForEach(group.cards) { card in
                                CardView(title: card.title, showEdit: $isEdit)
                                    .aspectRatio(card.height, contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width: card.style != .widget1x1 ? geo.size.width - 32 : (geo.size.width - 32) / 2)
                                    .onDrag {
                                        withAnimation(.default) {
                                            self.draggedCard = card
                                            return NSItemProvider()
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate:
                                                withAnimation(.default) {
                                        DropViewDelegate(destinationItem: card, cards: $cards, draggedItem: $draggedCard)})
                                    .background(self.draggedCard == card ? Color.clear : Color.clear)
                                    .padding(.vertical, isEdit ? 16 : 0)
                            }
                        }.padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                }
                .transaction { transaction in
                    transaction.animation = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func groupedCards() -> [CardGroup] {
        var result: [CardGroup] = []
        var currentGroup: [Card] = []
        
        for card in cards {
            if card.style != .widget1x1 {
                if !currentGroup.isEmpty {
                    result.append(CardGroup(cards: currentGroup))
                    currentGroup = []
                }
                result.append(CardGroup(cards: [card]))
            } else {
                if currentGroup.count == 1 {
                    if currentGroup.first?.style == .widget1x1 {
                        currentGroup.append(card)
                        result.append(CardGroup(cards: currentGroup))
                        currentGroup = []
                    } else {
                        result.append(CardGroup(cards: currentGroup))
                        currentGroup = [card]
                    }
                } else {
                    currentGroup.append(card)
                }
            }
        }
        
        if !currentGroup.isEmpty {
            result.append(CardGroup(cards: currentGroup))
        }
        
        return result
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct DropViewDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let destinationItem: Card
    @Binding var cards: [Card]
    @Binding var draggedItem: Card?
    
    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        return DropProposal(operation: .move)
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        draggedItem = nil
        return true
    }
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        if let draggedItem = draggedItem {
            let fromIndex = cards.firstIndex(of: draggedItem)
            if let fromIndex = fromIndex {
                let toIndex = self.cards.firstIndex(of: destinationItem)
                if let toIndex = toIndex, fromIndex != toIndex {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                        withAnimation(.default) {
                            self.cards.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: fromIndex), toOffset: (toIndex > fromIndex ? (toIndex + 1) : toIndex))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Could you help me figure out how to make the drag-and-drop animations as smooth as they were before grouping the 1x1-sized views into a single entity? Thank you very much!
